# Programmatically sending ping to networks which are not configured in Network Adapter Settings

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming

I am developing a C# application, where I have to find and list all IP Addresses in connected networks. Normally I can ping a device if I have done Network Adapter Settings (NAS) for that particular network. So the questions are:

- Is this possible to send ping request to a device for which Network
  Adapter settings is not configured?
- If possible, any code example, or a guide on how can I achieve this.
- Without NAS, how can I ping in C# with gateway set within the
  application and not in Network Adapter Settings?

In short, the behavior that I need to achieve is that, without any NAS, I need to create a Ping request in C# application for some specific IP-range provided by the user. For example, user can provide IP range as follows:

- 192.168.1.xxx
- 192.168.39.xxx etc.

Thanks.

For more clarification of the problem, here is the **example scenario**:

I can ping a device if the device has an IP Address 192.168.39.15, provided I have made network adapter settings as shown in picture below.

[image]

If I remove this Network Adapter Settings, it is no longer possible to ping this device. My objective is to still **ping the device even without this Network Adapter settings**.

Comment: How could someone flag a close vote where I am working purely on programming and this is a programming how-to question?

Comment: maybe you can get some inspiration from [nmap](http://nmap.org/)

Comment: I disagree with the close vote. Perhaps some users assumed that this was a Superuser question, but you are clearly asking about programmatically pinging in C#. However, I suggest rewording to ask a clear, answerable question rather than asking for a guide.

Comment: this perhaps is the worst example of moderation and closed votes. All people voting off-topic "do you clearly have any insight of what I asked"???? or u just love close-votes for your profile

Comment: I think that even if the question gets reopened, it will be closed again for being too broad. Like @Superbest said, try to rephrase your question in small, solveable blocks in stead of asking for "how to...".

Comment: Ok, I will try to rephrase it in my new edit

Answer (score 0):

This is how IP works. You either need to be on the same subnet as your device or have the default gateway set up. If none is the case there is no way knowing where to send the packet.

Answer (score 0):

Network settings not configured is situation like a person without any contact details. There is no way to find out such person until met physically. Similar is the situation here, configured network means providing identity to the connecting system in the network. Ping is also means of communication using the identity provided by the network. So, you wanna identify a system in a network, network settings should be properly configured.